# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"3", :school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the full error that I got while doing my project:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"3", >:school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Here are the lines that cause the error:

```
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
    @rating = @teacher.ratings.create(rating_params)
    redirect_to school_teacher_path(@school, @teacher)
  end

  private
```

Here are my route file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'users/new'

      resources :schools do
        resources :teachers
      end

      resources :users do
        resources :ratings
      end

      resources :teachers do
        resources :ratings
      end
```

And here is my ratings_controller.rb:

```
    def new
      @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
      rating = Rating.new
    end

   def create
     @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
     @rating = @teacher.ratings.create(rating_params)
     redirect_to school_teacher_path(@school, @teacher)
  end

  private

    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:student, :helpfulness,:clarity,:easiness, :comment)
    end
```

If I understand it correctly, is it because I didn't nest the ratings resources in my route file? And how can I prevent this error to happen in the future?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: What's in @school, cause it seems it's not passing a instantiation of the School model. Since you are using nested routes, Rails is expecting a school_id, which is what the error is indicating as missing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So, I need to pass the school id like this:
  redirect_to school_teacher_path(@school.id, @teacher) ?

Comment: Well, you need to pass the school to which the @teacher is related. So something like the answer of Marek Lipka. But I'm actually wondering why you should have a nested relation between school and teacher... could you elaborate on that? Isn't it a plain has_many :through of habtm?

Comment: @NeverGiveUp1989 no, it will raise `NoMethodError`, since your `@school` is `nil`.

Comment: The reason I have a nested relation between school and teacher because in project, a school will have many teachers, and a teacher will have many ratings from the students(and the students need to log in so that they can rate their teachers). I am just a newbie, so I don't know I understand this kind of relation correctly. I am following the rails blog tutorial. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory. You need to provide `school_id` to your nested route, but you don't set `@school` variable, so it's `nil`. This should work:

```
redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
```

or

```
redirect_to [@teacher.school, @teacher]
```

of course. you should have `school` association in your `Teacher` module.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Marek back on form :)

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to school_teacher_path(@school, @teacher)
```

You don't have `@school` available (you've not defined it).

You either need to set `@school` explicitly, or as `@Marek` mentioned, you should use the `school` association on `Teacher`:

```
@teacher = Teacher.find params[:teacher_id]
@school  = ? #=> could be @teacher.school
@rating  = @teacher.ratings.create rating_params
```

---

To give you some context, here's some information regarding the models/associations & how they fit into your app:

```
#app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :schools, through: :ratings
end

#app/models/rating.rb
class Rating < Activerecord::Base
   belongs_to :teacher
   belongs_to :school
   belongs_to :user #-> this does not feature in the has_many :through
end

#app/models/school.rb
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :teachers, through: :ratings
   #only problem here is there is no "central" record of teachers & schools
end
```

This gives you the ability to call the following:

```
@teacher = Teacher.find x
@teacher.ratings

@school = School.find y
@school.ratings

@ratings = Rating.where(teacher: @teacher)
@ratings = Rating.where(school: @school)

@teacher.rating.school #-> "school" for rating
```

Now, the important thing to note is that this setup is entirely in your *models*.

Rails is an **MVC** ([**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) framework -

[image]

This means that all your "data" logic should be kept in your *models*, your *controllers* & *views* should manage that data to create an output for the user.

--

Many newbies don't understand the difference between a "model", "controller" and "view". Here's how it works:

Rails is built on Ruby. Ruby is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

OOP (Object Orientated Programming) simply means populating variables with *classes* of data, containing both "attributes" and "methods". The variable can then be referred to as an *object*, with both the attributes being invoked from it, and the methods being used to perform actions on it.

OOP is used mainly in games:

[image]

... it allows you to keep a number of dynamic pieces of data in the application at once. In the example of a *game*, it means you're able to invoke a number of objects depending on what interaction the user has with the game.

In Mario, for example, each "enemy" will have a certain "path", and each time the player "moves" Mario (IE the mario object's position is redrawn), if it intersects one of the enemies, the Mario object will have his health depleted.

In *Rails*, we don't have the luxury of a stateful application ([HTTP is *stateless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)). Stateless applications (which Rails is) have to rebuild the "environment" each time the user sends a request.

This means that you have to ensure you're able to reconstruct the data objects you require each time you accept the request on the user's system. Hence if you have `redirect_to school_teacher_path(@school, @teacher)`, you need the `@school` and `@teacher` objects present in order for it to work.

--

The rebuilding of the "environment" is what *controllers* are for - they take the user's request, pull data from the *model* and factor it into a *view*.

When the request is completed, the controller then sends compiled HTML back to the browser, allowing the user to see the updated response. Your error occurs because you're not building the right data in your controller.

*Everything* in your app should be geared towards getting this data compilation process to work properly in your controller. Even the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teachers do
   resources :ratings #-> url.com/teachers/:teacher_id/ratings/:id
end
```

The above allows you to pass the following:

```
#app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @teacher = Teacher.find params[:teacher_id]
      @rating = @teacher.ratings.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You said that I need to use the school association on Teacher. I think I already did that in my route file. If I understand it wrong, please correct me. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes but routes != associations. In order for an association to be invoked into data / variables, it has to exist in the *models*. I can write about this more if you need.

Comment: Please do because I am learning Rails so I am willing to learn to from everybody. Or you can give me the source, I will check it by myself.

Comment: Sure, let me get some breakfast then I'll do it.

Comment: Ok, sir. Take your time. No hurry. By the way, I think it will be easier for you if you understand the goal of my project. Here, I am doing a clone of the website ratemyprofessor.com. I have the data model for schools, teachers, users, and ratings. One school will have many teachers, and a teacher can have many schools(because in Asia, one teacher can teach at different schools), one user will have many ratings for their teachers, and a teacher will have many ratings. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Updated, it might be a bit long winded but should help you appreciate how it works

Comment: Thank you very much for such a useful information. I appreciate it. Have a good day, sir.